# Debian system wide locale not being followed

Tags: linux, debian

contents of /etc/default/locale:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

locale command output:

```
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Why isn't LANG being set?

Note: I have no .bashrc or .profile

Comment: Does `locale -a` show that `en_US.UTF-8` is a valid installed locale? It doesn't on my Debian wheezy system - the proper name is `en_US.utf8`...

Comment: Output of locale -a:

`locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8
`

Comment: So you probably ought to fix `/etc/default/locale` to say `LANG=en_US.utf8`...

Comment: Would that be a bug in dpkg-reconfigure locales? Since that's what I used to generate it

Comment: it's also named en_US.UTF-8 in /etc/locale.gen

Comment: I changed it to en_US.utf8 just to see, still no go.

Comment: The only other difference I see on my Debian wheezy box is that it says `LANG="en_US.utf8"` - i.e. the variables value is quoted...

Comment: obviously adding `export PATH=~/bin:$PATH` to my `.zshrc` works, but I wish it would read it system-wide. If it matters, this is a SSH connection using Putty

Answer (score 0):

The only clean thing that worked for me was this from https://wiki.debian.org/Locale

> Add a line like this to your /etc/profile file:

```
: "${LANG:=en_US.utf8}"; export LANG
```